# Do we have Admob support for Coroa SDK yet ..?

Tags: iphone, admob, coronasdk

I want to know if there is support for Admob in Corona SDK ? I am searching for it, I also managed to find some threads, which says " Admob support is NOT YET added in Corona SDK", but the posts are pretty old.

For now, at this point of time.. Has Corona added support for Admob..?

Answer (score 1):

Corona SDK now officially supports AdMob: http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/plugin/ads-admob/

Answer (score 0):

No, Corona do not supports AdMob (yet...)

But there are in the forum some hacks to get it working on Android.

I don't saw a hack to make it work on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

AdMob is not officially supported by Corona SDK. You can use a work around available on GitHub called AdMediator. Doing so potentially risks your account with AdMob due to being an unofficial method.

You used to be able to utilise Adsense style ads via a WebView but this has been phased out by Google.

[AdMediator for Corona SDK](https://github.com/deniza/Ad-Mediator-for-Corona/wiki/Documentation)